# How to add images in anchor

Tags: html, css

In my application i am using a reference of a website which contains a feature refer which is also changing on mouseover. [Sample website](http://www.ureferjobs.com/companies/balanced-labs/jobs/ios-lead)

In my code i am doing  this to make that refer icon just like the website

```
<a href="<%=redirectUserURL.toString() %>&<portlet:namespace/>jobID=<%=job %>" id="applyJobSearch"><img class="referIcon" />Refer</a>
```

But i am not able  to make that like that.I have attached the website url somebody please

Answer (score 1):

The image tag will be expecting an image source as it is a required attribute.  If you are wanting to have an image which is the background image set in a class, then use `<span>` tags to display them.

You'll then end up with something like:

```
<a href="<%=redirectUserURL.toString() %>&<portlet:namespace/>jobID=<%=job %>" id="applyJobSearch">
    <span class="referIcon"></span>Refer
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="<%=redirectUserURL.toString() %>&<portlet:namespace/>jobID=<%=job %>" id="applyJobSearch">
    <span class="referIcon">Refer</span>
</a>
```

Depending on your preference.

Comment: yah that worked ,but how i can change the image on mouseover

Comment: In your css you can set the style for `.referIcon:hover` to have a different background image.  This works best if you use the second code option in my answer as it will work when the text is hovered over too (as it's part of the span)

Comment: i have used the first one but image is not coming this is my css .referIcon{
        background: url("../images/icons/refer.png");
        background-position: 30% 20%;
        
}

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below

```
<a href="http://somesite.com">
 <img border="0" alt="Logo" src="logo.gif" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that example image displaying in :before element of i

```
<span> <i class="icon"></i>refer </span>
```

CSS
    .icon:before {
      content: "\f1d8";
    }

you need to use the font family too

font-family: "proxima-nova", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;